# Invariant quantity from commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02785666.pdf) paper on conformal quantum mechanics by De Alfaro, Fubini, and Furlan. There, they find the algebra of the generators of $(0+1)$-D conformal transformations (Eq. 2.23)
$$
[H,D] = iH\;, \qquad [K,D] = -iK\;, \qquad [H,K] = 2iD\;.
$$
Here $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator, $D$ is the dilatation generator, and $K$ is the special conformal operator in $(0+1)$-D. On the next page, they define an operator
$$
G = uH+vD+wK
$$
where $u, v,w$ are constants. Next, they say that from the commutator relation it is easy to see that the quantity $\Delta = v^2-4uw$ is invariant with respect to any general conformal transformation $G\rightarrow U^{-1}GU$.

I can check that this is true using any $U$. But what I do not understand is how one can "easily" determine what the expression of $\Delta$ should be just from looking at the commutation relations? How do they get this $\Delta$?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps de Alfaro et al note that$$\left[G,\,\left(\begin{array}{c}
D\\
H\\
K
\end{array}\right)\right]=iM\left(\begin{array}{c}
D\\
H\\
K
\end{array}\right),\,M:=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & u & -w\\
-2w & -v & 0\\
2u & 0 & v
\end{array}\right).$$Since $M$ is singular and traceless, its eigenvalues are of the form $0,\,\pm\lambda$. If we diagonalize to isolate the $0$ eigenvalue, the others' product should be a homogeneous quadratic, so $\lambda$ is a square root thereof. And it comes as no surprise, given how quadratic equations work, that $\lambda=\sqrt{v^2-4uw}$.

Note in particular we don't need to compute $M$ to realize that, nor to realize it will be singular ($G$ gives an obvious kernel element) or traceless (that just requires the "self-interacting" commutators $[H,\,D],\,[K,\,D]$ to have opposite coefficients).